# Play Framework Persistence Unit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, persistence

I have this issue with Play:

**PersistenceException: Unable to locate persistence units**

I have config my persistence unit in persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="ProductPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>models.Product</class>

    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>ProductDB</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And on the application.conf:

```
jpa.default:ProductPersistenceUnit
```

So what is going on?

Comment: Where did you created that `persistence.xml`?

Comment: Hi Machina, i created in conf/META-INF

Answer (score 0):

Use = instead of :

```
jpa.default=ProductPersistenceUnit
```